# String comparison doesn't seem to work for lines read from a file

Tags: python

I have a file named `test.txt` that contains the following:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
```

I have simple Python program like this:

```
f = open("test.txt")

myline = "Line 3"
for line in f:
    print myline + " - " + line
    if myline == line:
        print "We have a match!"

if myline == "Line 3":
    print "This works."
```

I got this result:

```
Line 3 - Line 1

Line 3 - Line 2

Line 3 - Line 3

Line 3 - Line 4

This works.
```

Why doesn't "We have a match!" get printed?

What did I miss?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why doesn't "We have a match!" get printed? What did I miss?

If you will notice the output on console you are getting *double* `\n` (newlines) one because of `print` second because in file every line has `\n` at the end. Your file that looks like:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
```

is basically: `Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nLine 4` (assuming you don't have any extra white spaces e.g. tabs, blank space).

In for loop: `for line in f:`,  end char of `line` is `\n` (and `line` that you think is `'Line 3'` is actually `'Line 3\n'`) Hence your `if` condition *fails*.

To remove that `\n` just use [`str.strip([chars]);`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm) function. The method `strip()` returns a copy of the string in which all chars have been stripped from the beginning and the end of the string (default whitespace characters).

So, replace `if myline == line:` by `if myline == line.strip()` that is what @C.B.'s answer.

Comment: New line characters known to be appeared as `\r\n` in same cases.

Comment: @FallenAngel Yes, Basically depends on os  I think. I have experience on Linux it is always `\n` (if I am correct) I explain this answer because many time when I was new I suffer with this bug.

Answer (score 6):

[Strip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) the newline character:

```
for line in f:
    print myline + " - " + line
    if myline == line.strip():
        print "We have a match!"
```